# Thymeleaf pass data from html id to thymeleaf variable

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I've a problem with below code. I need to pass a variable from html id to thymeleaf variable.

```html
<table class="responsive-table highlight bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <tr th:each="worker: ${workersList}">
        <td th:text="${worker.id}"></td>
        <td th:text="${worker.name}"></td>
        <td th:text="${worker.surname}"></td>
        <td th:text="${worker.email}"></td>

        <td>
            <a href="#deleteModal" class="btn tooltipped modal-trigger" th:attr="data-id=${worker.id}, data-name=${worker.name +' '+ worker.surname}"
               data-position="top" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Delete"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <!-- Delete Modal -->
    <div id="deleteModal" class="modal modal-fixed-footer">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <p id="modal-name"></p>
            <p id="modal-id"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a th:href="@{'/delete/'+${modal-id} }" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-red btn-flat">Yes</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    </tbody>
</table>

<script th:inline="javascript">
    $('#deleteModal').modal({
        ready: function(modal, trigger) {
            var button = $(trigger);
            var id = button.data('id');
            $('#modal-id').html(id);
        }
    });
</script>
```

It won't work. I've to pass it using js because this id's are changeable depends on worker I click. This works, but It can't pass an id to th:href Thanks for help!

Comment: It is not so clear what you are trying to do, sorry. May be changing `th:href="@{/delete/{id} (id=${modal-id})}"` with `th:href="@{|/delete/${worker.id}}"` could help.

Comment: I can't pass there ${worker.id} because through that I've always only first id from list of all workers.

Comment: try to change `<a th:href="@{'/delete/'+${modal-id} }" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-red btn-flat">Yes</a>` with `<a id="confirm" href="/delete/" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-red btn-flat">Yes</a>` and `$('#modal-id').html(id);` with `var baseurl = $('#confirm').attr('href'); $('#confim').attr('href',baseurl + id);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They way you have it done, you need to use Javascript to update the ID, as your modal is outside the loop. I would do something like this:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <a id="idModalLink" href="#" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-red btn-flat">Yes</a>
</div>
```

And in your javascript code:

```
$('#deleteModal').modal({
    ready: function(modal, trigger) {
        var button = $(trigger);
        var id = button.data('id');
        $('#modal-id').html(id);
        $('#idModalLink').attr("href", "/delete/" + id);
    }
});
```

Comment: Won't work. When I create sth like this  <p id="modal-id">{here is the value}</p>

Comment: @johnson which error? If you have some value for "modal-id" in your controller have to work.

Comment: <p id="modal-id">here i get the correct value</p>
How to use id from html to pass it to thymeleaf? I don't use controller for this id

Comment: but then where do you get this id from?

Comment: from javascript which is shown on this page upper ^^

Comment: and the value is inside <p> tag, but I want to pass it to thymeleaf after "delete/{here}"

Comment: I can not find the p tag in your question, could do you add it?

Comment: There is no <p> tag in question but here in chat, because I put it to test if the value is there, and it's there, so only the problem is with passing it to the th:href="@{/delete/{here}"

Comment: and how do you print the value inside the p in your example? share that code please here

Comment: just using this <p id="modal-id"></p> I see on the page the correct value, it means that "modal-id" has the correct value but I don't know to pass it to thymeleaf

Comment: Yes, but then to write the value of "modal-id" in your id attribute, you have to use some thymeleaf syntax like <p id="${modal-id}">XX</p> or something similar right?

Comment: I want to get the value from "modal-id"
I do it sth like that, won't work -> <a th:href="@{'/delete/'+${modal-id}}" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-red btn-flat">Yes</a>

Comment: Just try to add to your ModelAndView from your controller some unique id for the attribute "model-id" then should work. Or use ${worker.id} <a th:href="@{'/delete/'+${worker.id}}" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-red btn-flat">Yes</a>

Comment: I can't use ${worker.id} because I've there a loop in thymeleaf and have always the first element from list. This is a common problem. But this idea with controller it's bad, so what can I pass to the variable from controller if I don't have a current clicked worker from list

Comment: @johnson add to your question the full code with the loop, and i will find some good option to help you

Comment: It would be easy to get current worker id just by passing ${worker.id} but It always give me only the first worker from list of all workers. I've made a research but this is a common problem, and the help solution is with this javascript.